# Rashi, Tosfot - Dialects

Tags: hebrew, rashi, language, aramaic, tosfot

Is there a name for the dialect of Hebrew/Aramaic that Rashi and Tosfot use? Have there been any articles and/or books published on how to systematically approach Rashi and the Baalei Tosfot's language grammatically?

I ask since on the one hand, Rashi uses Hebrew personal pronouns, but might also use vocabulary such as "ילפינן" ,"ליכא" ,"איכא", etc., which are Aramaic. Tosfot appears to have similar characteristics. So does this "dialect" count as Hebrew, Aramaic, or some mixture?

Comment: I believe it's called [Medieval Hebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_Hebrew). :) But I'm not sure if this is on-topic for this site.

Comment: The book called ‘tools for tosafos’ talks about this. But in reality it probably can be categorized as ׳לשון דרבנן׳. Also note that the Talmud itself doesn’t stick to one language.

Comment: I don't know if there is a formal term but this diglossic language is commonly termed '*lashon soferim*' or '*lashon chachamim*'.

Comment: Doesn't write something about this Saenz-Badillos?