# Why did Rashi choose Hebrew over Aramaic?

Tags: hebrew, commentaries, rashi

Rashi chose a form of [Medieval Hebrew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93052/15256) to write his commentaries, which facilitates the life of many students, as the Aramaic content in his writing is very low compared to the Gemara or [contemporary liturgical poems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akdamut). In the [introduction](http://mechon-mamre.org/e/e0000.htm) of Mishneh Torah Rambam discusses the issue that Jews of his age were not excelling in Aramaic (see paragraphs 36, 40, 41), which might have been Rashi's concern too.

Did Rashi write about his motivations for choosing Hebrew in a similar way?

Comment: Almost all the Rishonim wrote their *pirushim* in *lashon hakodesh*. The Rambam's Pirush Mishnayos was one of the few Rishonic commentaries that required translation. Why do you ask on Rashi specifically, and what exactly is the question?

Comment: @chortkov2 Rashi is among the first _Rishonim,_ so others might have just followed him. The question is written explicitly: Was Rashi concerned with the bad Aramaic knowledge of his contemporaries? Did he have other motivations with the _lashon hakodesh?_

Comment: Pretty much everyone wrote in Hebrew, or in the vernacular. Rashi has no reason to write in Aramaic, which was not spoken locally. I cannot think of any commentary written in Aramaic.

Comment: @simyou Using your logic, he could have written in French as Chazal were writing in Aramaic and Rambam has works in Arabic. But he didn't, even though in many cases he used French words that were better understood in his environment.

Comment: My personal impression is that the Torah study wasn't so widespread as we might think as not many people could afford to have [access to] books. If so, Rashi wasn't addressing the wide audience, but only Torah schoolers, who are "fluent" in Hebrew anyway.

Comment: @AlBerko Those people, including Rashi, knew very well Aramaic...

Comment: Right, I was only addressing "why not French".

Comment: Rashi wasn't the first to write in Hebrew. Rabbenu Gershom, RY Ben Yakar, Menachem, Dunash, Rabbenu Chanan'el, even Rav Hay Ga'on whose father wrote in Aramaic wrote (partially) in Hebrew (and the rest, I think, in Arabic)

Comment: @ba Shall I generalise the question to the early Rishonim of Ashkenaz? (As you're the second one to complain about it.)

Comment: @Kazibácsi I think the early Rishonim of Ashkenaz ([such as these](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94), Akdamut notwithstanding) did write generally in Hebrew. (And it wasn't a complaint, I was just pointing out that Rashi wasn't necessarily one of the first and that the other rishonim must have followed him as you suggested)

Comment: @ba I remember having read that the contemporaries of Saadia Gaon were not entirely happy that he wrote in Arabic instead of Aramaic. With this logic these Rishonim of Ashkenaz could have written in French, but they insisted on Hebrew. (In the light of the multi-lingualism of the Talmud, your deleted idea about the midrashim wouldn't be a strong reason.)

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: @Kazibácsi Of the midrashim (midreshey halacha or aggada) that Rashi quotes in his commentary to the Torah, almost all of them are from Hebrew sources. Even the Talmud uses Hebrew almost exclusively in commentary on the Torah

Comment: One general strategy I've noticed about Rash"i is that he sticks to *pshat* on a "fundamental level", unless a Midrash is really needed. Of course, he frequently supplements the pshat with Midrash, but rarely do you see him offer only Midrash. So when he explains a word, he will cite another Hebrew verse from elsewhere in Tanac"h, which is most often in Hebrew. He also refers to one of the famed lexicologists of that era (I can't recall his name, now.) Occasionally, he refers to Targum. In short, If he's explaining shoresh or dikduk, seems to stick to Hebrew as much as he can.